# Spring ws : how to access to the size of an AxiomAttachment

Tags: java, spring-ws

In order to get an attachment i have the following code in an endpoint :

```
@PayloadRoot(localPart = REQUEST_ELEMENT, namespace = MODELES_V1_0_URI)
@ResponsePayload
public Source saveFile(MessageContext argo) throws Exception {

 (AxiomSoapMessage)MessageContextHolder.getMessageContext().getRequest();
 AxiomSoapMessage request = (AxiomSoapMessage)argo.getRequest();
 Attachment attachement= request.getAttachments().next();
```

But the attachment implements AxiomAttachment (i'm using AxiomSoapMessageFactory) and according to this class " Axiom does not support getting the size of attachments.".

**How can i get the size of the attachement ?**

Iv try to use this in order to be able to send big files (more than 10 mo) as an attachement to prevent an outofMemory (any better idea will be appreciate - i have already try the mtom spring sample but it doesnt work with heavy file (outOfMemory too) even by specifying the AxiomSoapMessageFactory).

***Im open to any better solution (the spring ws mtom sample doesnt work..) for dealing with heavy file with spring ws***

Comment: You'll almost certainly get a better response to this on the Spring-WS forum: http://forum.springsource.org/forumdisplay.php?f=39

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible to get the size of a file before you save it off from the DataHandler. Think about it. MTOM is a technology to stream binary files to a web service. The question you've asked is akin to saying "How long is this telephone call going to last?" You can't know for sure until you've hung up the phone.